# Yii2- Unable to pass model from controller to view

Tags: php, model, yii2, undefined, yii2-advanced-app

I am working on `Yii2`. I have a controller in which I am doing the following.

```
 /**
 * @param $id
 * @return string|\yii\web\Response
 * @throws NotFoundHttpException
 * @throws \Exception
 * @throws \yii\db\Exception
 * @throws \yii\db\StaleObjectException
 */

 public function actionViewcreated($id)// passed the id of my model which is created in the previous step
{
    $params = "";
    //print_r('hi');

    $model= $this->findModel($id); // this will find my model/record based on the id

    $sub_div = $model->sub_div;
    $meter_type = $model->meter_type;

    $query = /** @lang text */
        "SELECT DISTINCT m.`id` AS meter_id, ins.`meter_msn` AS Meter_Serial_Number, ins.`meter_type` AS Meter_Type, sd.`sub_div_code` AS Sub_Division_Code,sd.`name` AS Sub_Division_Name 
FROM `installations` ins 
INNER JOIN `meters` m ON ins.`meter_msn` = m.`meter_msn`
INNER JOIN `meter_acceptance_header` map ON ins.`meter_type` = map.`meter_type`
INNER JOIN `survey` sur ON ins.`ref_no` = sur.`ref_no` 
INNER JOIN `survey_hesco_subdivision` sd ON sur.`sub_division` = sd.`sub_div_code` 
WHERE ins.`meter_type` = '$meter_type' 
AND sd.`sub_div_code` = '$sub_div' 
AND m.`id` NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT md.`meter_id` FROM 
`meter_acceptance_details` md WHERE md.`flag` IN (1))";


    $session = Yii::$app->session;
    $session->set('my_sql', $query);

    $sqlCount= /** @lang text */
        "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT m.`id`)  
FROM `installations` ins 
INNER JOIN `meters` m ON ins.`meter_msn` = m.`meter_msn`
INNER JOIN `meter_acceptance_header` map ON ins.`meter_type` = map.`meter_type` 
INNER JOIN `survey` sur ON ins.`ref_no` = sur.`ref_no` 
INNER JOIN `survey_hesco_subdivision` sd ON sur.`sub_division` = sd.`sub_div_code` 
WHERE ins.`meter_type` = '$meter_type' 
AND sd.`sub_div_code` = '$sub_div' 
AND m.`id` NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT md.`meter_id` FROM `meter_acceptance_details` md WHERE md.`flag` IN (1))";

    $params = Yii::$app->request->queryParams;
    //print_r(isset($params->Meter_Serial_Number));
    if(isset($params['Meter_Serial_Number']) && $params['Meter_Serial_Number']!==''){
        $query.="AND WHERE (ins.`meter_msn`='".$params['Meter_Serial_Number']."')";
        $sqlCount="AND WHERE (ins.`meter_msn`='".$params['Meter_Serial_Number']."')";
    }
    if(isset($params['Sub_Division_Name'])&&$params['Sub_Division_Name']!==''){
        $query.="AND WHERE (sd.`name`='".$params['Sub_Division_Name']."')";
        $sqlCount.="AND WHERE (sd.`name`='".$params['Sub_Division_Name']."')";
    }
    //print_r($query);
    $count = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sqlCount)->queryScalar();

    $session = Yii::$app->session;
    $session->set('total', $count);


    if($count <= 0)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->delete();

        \Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('errors', '
       <div class="alert alert-error alert-dismissable">
       <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="alert" class="close" 
       type="button">×</button>
       <strong>There are no meters installed against the selected Sub Division!!!! </strong>Acceptance is not Created</div>');


        return $this->redirect(['index', 'id' => $model->id]);
    }
    else
    {
        $dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
            'sql' => $query,
            'totalCount' => $count,
            'pagination' => false,
        ]);


        return $this->render('viewcreated', [
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'model' =>$model,
            'id' => $model->id

        ]);
    }
}
```

**View**

```
$this->title = $model->id;
$this->title = 'Meter Acceptance Form';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
.
.
.
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>
        <?= DetailView::widget([
            'model' => $model,
            'attributes' => [

                [
                        'label'=>'Serial #',
                         'value' => function($d)
                         {
                             return $d->id;
                         }
                ],
                [
                    'label' => 'Meter Type',
                    'value' => function ($d) {
                        if(is_object($d))
                            return $d->meter_type;
                        return ' - ';
                    },


                ],
                'sub_div',
                [
                    'label' => 'Sub Division Name',
                    'value' => function ($d) {
                        if(is_object($d))
                            return $d->subDiv->name;
                        return '-';
                    },


                ],
                [
                    'label' => 'Prepared By',
                    'value' => function ($d) {
                        if(is_object($d))
                            return $d->prepared->name;
                    },


                ],
                'prepared_at',

                'status',


            ],
        ]) ?>
  .
  .
  .
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
  .
  .
  .
<a href="<?= URL::toRoute(['meteracceptanceheader/viewprocess', 'id'=>$model->id])?>" name="redirect" class="btn btn-primary" id="myid">Submit</a>
```

When I press the `Submit` button I am getting the following error

> PHP Notice 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Undefined variable: model'
>
> in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\inventory-web\backend\views\meteracceptanceheader\viewcreated.php:17

And line 17 is `$this->title = $model->id;`

How can I get rid of this issue?

**Update 1**

By doing `print_r($model); exit();` I got the following result

`common\models\MeterAcceptanceHeader Object ( [_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array ( [id] => 1 [sub_div] => 37111 [meter_type] => L.T.TOU [prepared_by] => 12 [prepared_at] => 2018-08-03 08:39:22 [updated_at] => [status] => Prepared ) [_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array ( [id] => 1 [sub_div] => 37111 [meter_type] => L.T.TOU [prepared_by] => 12 [prepared_at] => 2018-08-03 08:39:22 [updated_at] => [status] => Prepared ) [_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array ( ) [_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => [_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => [_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array ( ) [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array ( ) )`

**Update 2:**

**View Process Controller**

```
/**
 * @param $id
 * @return \yii\web\Response
 * @throws NotFoundHttpException
 * @throws \Exception
 * @throws \yii\db\StaleObjectException
 */
public function actionViewprocess($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $accpt_id = $model->id;
    $meter_type = $model->meter_type;
    $ogp_sub_div = $model->sub_div;


    if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax && Yii::$app->request->post())
    {
        $data = explode(',',$_POST['data']);

        foreach($data as $value)
        {

            $m = new MeterAcceptanceDetails;
            $m -> load(Yii::$app->request->post());

            $m->accpt_id = $accpt_id;
            $m->meter_type = $meter_type;
            $m->created_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $m->meter_id = $value;
            $m->meter_msn = \common\models\Meters::idTomsn($value);
            $m->flag = 1;// 1 means created
            $m->ogp_sub_div = $ogp_sub_div;

            if($m->save())
            {
                $model->status = MeterAcceptanceHeader::$status_titles[1];
                $model->update();

            }
            else{
                $this->renderAjax('viewcreated');
            }
        }

    }
    else{
        $this->renderAjax('viewcreated');
    }
    $query = /** @lang text */
        "SELECT DISTINCT a.`id` AS Accpt_Id,u.`name` AS Prepared_By,b.`meter_msn` AS Meter_Serial_Number, b.`meter_type` AS Meter_Type, 
        sd.`name` AS Sub_Div_Name,DATE(b.`created_at`) AS 'Date' FROM 
        `meter_acceptance_header` a
        INNER JOIN `meter_acceptance_details` b ON a.`id` = b.`accpt_id`
        INNER JOIN `survey_hesco_subdivision` sd ON b.`ogp_sub_div` = sd.`sub_div_code`
        INNER JOIN `user` u ON a.`prepared_by` = u.`id` 
        WHERE b.`accpt_id` =$accpt_id AND b.`meter_type` = '$meter_type'";


    return $this->redirect(Url::toRoute(['meteracceptanceheader/viewprocess','id' => $model->id, 'model' => $this->findModel($id)]));

}
```

**View Process View**

```
$this->title = $model->id;
$this->title = 'Meter Acceptance';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;

<section class="content-header">
<h1>Meter Acceptance</h1>
</section>
<section class="content">
<div class="box">
    <div class="box-body">
      <?= GridView::widget([
         'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
       'columns' => [

           ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
           [
               'label'=>'Serial #',
               'value' => 'Accpt_Id'
           ],

           'Date',
           'Prepared_By',
           'Meter_Serial_Number',
           'Meter_Type',
           'Sub_Div_Name',
 ],
]); ?>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you give whole controller action?

Comment: updated the code

Comment: Can you do print_r($model);exit; before return $this->render...

Comment: @tigrasti Kindly check my `update 1`

Comment: The error ocur when you go to view page, or press submit?

Comment: When I press the submit button

Comment: The problem is in the viewprocess action or view. Please paste here both

Comment: @tigrasti check my `update 2`

Comment: If you are not going to viewprocess page, then problem must be in $this->renderAjax('viewcreated'); You must pass here model. Try that.

Comment: @tigrasti I am going to `viewprocess` page `$this->renderAjax('viewcreated');` is the else part.
I have already used the same flow on another module in my project. I don't know why it's not working here

Comment: You are not passing $model variable, that is the problem. And problem occur on viewcreated page, just pass $this->renderAjax('viewcreated', ['model'=>$model]); and the check the error. That is what I think that can be problem. The whole cation look kinda weird, I don't know what is your idea.

Comment: @tigrasti now I am getting `Undefined variable: dataProvider`

Comment: Yeah, thats it then. You must define variables that you have on viewcreated page, like you do in viewcreated action 'viewcreated', [
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'model' =>$model,
            'id' => $model->id

        ]);

Comment: you are using a anchor link to submit to the viewprocess and then in the action you are checking if not `isAjax or isPost` then in the else part you call `$this->renderAjax('viewcreated')` , and here is the main problem you are not passing the `$model ` with the view which is required and hence gives you error on the very first line `$this->title = $model->id;` which is in the exception too, you should either pass allt he required vars for the view if you are trying to render it from another action or redirect to that action rather than using `renderAjax()`

Comment: you need to pass `'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'model' =>$model,
            'id' => $model->id` all three if you wan to `renderAjax()` or redirect to the controller action

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam yes this has solved my issue. But I am still waiting :)

Comment: @tigrasti Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an anchor link to submit to the `viewprocess`

```
<a href="<?= URL::toRoute(['meteracceptanceheader/viewprocess', 'id'=>$model->id])?>" name="redirect" class="btn btn-primary" id="myid">Submit</a>
```

which resolves to a `GET` request and then in the `actionViewprocess` you are checking

```
if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax && Yii::$app->request->post())
```

which resolves to false and the control goes to the else part where you call

```
$this->renderAjax('viewcreated')
```

, and here is the main problem you are not passing the `$model` with the view which is required and hence gives you error on the very first line

```
$this->title = $model->id;
```

which is in the exception too, you should either pass all the required vars for the view if you are trying to render it from another action or `redirect` to that action rather than using `renderAjax()`

Answer (score -2):

Most likely your model doesn't include phodoc comment which includes the field descriptions. Ie. on top of your model class, you should have a comment like this:

```
/**
* This is the model class for table "applications".
*
* @property integer $id
* @property integer $someotherfield
*/
```

NOTE: you have posted controller code, but the functionality there would belong to model as per MVC principles. If this comment doesn't help, please post also your model code.

Comment: It's already added `/**
 * This is the model class for table "meter_acceptance_header".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $sub_div
 * @property string $meter_type
 * @property integer $prepared_by
 * @property string $prepared_at
 * @property string $updated_at
 * @property string $status
 *
 * @property MeterAcceptanceDetails[] $meterAcceptanceDetails
 * @property SurveyHescoSubdivision $subDiv
 * @property User $preparedBy
 */`

Comment: They need to be above the class, not above the function. Its best, if you post full PHP file contents, clearly marking which is model, which is controller and which is view so its little easier to help.

And again, if the first function there is your model code, it includes things that belong to a controller (and view, HTML doesn't belong into model).